# How can I get rid of oxidisation of my soldering tip?

Tags: soldering

I recently installed a new tip on my soldering iron, but when heating it up for the first time (target temperature: +370 °C), it got a reddish plaque (some kinda oxide, I suppose), so that it it's very hard to melt (lead-free) soldering wire, and the tip doesn't pick up anything of the solder. Using a cleaning stone (ammonium chloride) and a wet sponge removed the oxide just for a couple of seconds. After that, the stone was covered in brownish plaque I have never seen when using the old tip:

[image]

I followed the advice of the manufacturer and removed the plaque by using a Dremel with a wire brush head and after that polished the tip, but upon the next try, the tip was covered with the same reddish plaque again.

What's wrong with my soldering tip? Is it broken? Or did I buy the wrong tip?

Comment: Did you buy it from a recognized dealer in soldering equipment? Or, did you buy it from peeBay, maliexpress, shamazon etc..

Comment: Does your soldering wire have a flux core?

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes. I've always used thw same wire.

Comment: Try a tip tinning product like [one of these](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/solder-sponges-tip-cleaners/263?s=N4IgTCBcDaIMoHsA2ATApgJwAQBcCWAdgZliALoC%2BQA).

Comment: @RussellH OK, I'll give it a try. Shall I remove the oxide from the tip before applying the tinner, as I have already done once?

Comment: Try and see. The tip may not be recoverable. Choose a tip with nickel or chrome plating. Don’t use aluminum-chloride to remove oxidation. Use proper solder flux. Wash the tip with 99% isopropyl alcohol. Then thoroughly dry. Don’t use any abrasive material. Brass wool is a good scrubber.

Comment: 370C is quite hot. At that temp, the flux in the solder wire will last for a very short time, and oxidation will happen very fast. And ammonium chloride sounds like it could damage the plating (in general, acids and chlorides). The key to making it last is to be gentle with the plating (both in terms of chemical and abrasive), do regularly use mild flux in solder to chemically remove oxidation before it has a chance to build up a permanent layer, then remove the byproducts of that chemical reaction (which reduces the oxides) using wet sponge or brass. And don't overcook without a good reason

Comment: @PeteW +370 °C is exactly the temperature recommended by the vendor of the soldering wire.

Comment: @Neppomuk - Depends what you're working on. For small stuff, I agree with 275-300C in the answer below. Standard lead free solder. I found having not too small a point on the iron also reduces the need for higher temp... play around with it

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Soldering iron tip gets oxidised](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/700453/6102) Don't use clean your solder tips with various inappropriate tools. It's not a screwdriver.

Comment: Now the real question is where you bought this tip and of what brand. We do already have millions of questions about "I bought cheap crap at Aliexpress and it isn't working" elsewhere on the site.

Comment: That isn't oxidation, that is rust. You need a new tip, the surface has been ruined

Comment: So reactivation won't help here any more…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when heating it up for the first time (target temperature: +370 °C), it got a reddish plaque

That's a junk tip. I've never had a tip behave this way, and I've been soldering, initially with Weller in the 80s-00s, then later also with Hakko. Throw the tip away. If it is a Hakko reproduction tip, just buy the real thing. If the iron doesn't use reproduction tips, but something custom (not likely I hope), you may have luck looking for compatible tips from Asian brands that specialize in replacement tips. Some of those can be pretty good. But please, don't buy random tips on Amazon or Aliexpress and such. Any savings in parts cost will be quickly erased by lost productivity and aggravation of fighting with tips - something you never have to do when the tips and technique are good.

As others have said, 370°C is quite hot. Leaded solder melts under 200°C, so with a decent soldering iron, 275-300°C is plenty enough. When it's not enough, use hot air to heat the board/parts a bit, rather than cranking up the iron temp.

Even at 370°C though, a good tip should last much, much longer than just one heat cycle!

> ammonium chloride

Throw that stuff away. I can assure you that you don't need it, and I have never seen it used for fine work on an electronics bench. I'm sure I'm not some soldering prodigy who magically managed 30 years of soldering without using it nor seeing anyone use it on the bench. If anything, a *novice* should never use it for electronics soldering period. It's useful for "tips" on very large soldering irons used for flameless soldering of pipe or enclosures, larger hardline and such. For board-level work? Nope.

To prolong tip life, keep the iron temperature around 150-200°C when idling, and bring it up by 50-75°C only when soldering; get a heat gun or better a thick air "pencil" to preheat the piece you work on; get liquid flux in addition to flux in the soldering wire. Higher-end irons have an accelerometer in the handle and do this automatically. You should manage to do it manually just fine, it just needs to become a force of habit.

Comment: Really good advice, thx. BUT: My soldering station does not support such a regime. It simply heats up the iron to the preset temperature and then gives the iron another boost of current when it cools down. Don't say I've also gotta replace the soldering station!

Comment: @Neppomuk Good soldering stations do have that feature; Weller makes some that reduce the temperature when an accelerometer senses that the iron isn't being moved for a few minutes, JBC makes ones that use a magnet to detect when the iron is in the holder and reduce the temperature then, and I'm sure there are ones from Hakko that have a similar feature. When you *do* replace your soldering station (what model is it, anyway?), I suggest you look for that as a feature.

Comment: Even better to preheat the workpiece is a preheat plate. I use a Weller WHP200 at work, and it makes a world of difference, even when using hot air to rework things.

Comment: @Hearth It's a no-name product bought from an electronics retailer around the corner.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 370°C. It will reduce the tip life ever so slightly, but it won't explain the problem the OP is having. 275-300° is a newbie or pre-RoHS setting. Nothing wrong with that, but it will take longer to solder every joint.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you bought a bad tip.  A new tip should not behave that way.  I would recommend trying a different tip from another manufacturer.

Comment: Are soldering tips standardised so that I can buy the tip from whoever, and it will fit into the handle?

Comment: Yes, soldering tips are made specific for the manufacturer's model of the soldering iron used.  It should fit the model of soldering iron it was designed for regardless of the manufacturer of the soldering tip.  If it doesn't, then there is a problem.  Researching the soldering tip before you buy it may reveal any issues identified by previous customers.

Comment: @Neppomuk No - this answer is plain bad advise. You should only ever buy original tips from the solder iron manufacturer, period. There is no such thing as tip standardization. There are however, cheap, bad copycat products which is quite likely the reason why you ended up with this bad tip in the first place. In a worst case scenario, buying copycat tips is a fire hazard.

Answer (score 2):

> removed the plaque by using a Dremel with a wire brush head

Unless that wire brush head uses brass or copper wire, this is something you should *never* do. It's not as bad as sandpaper (which I've seen people use...) but mechanical abrasion with anything harder than brass wool (including the steel wire brushes that usually come with dremels) should never be used to clean a soldering tip. It'd probably be fine if you just brushed it a little manually, but using a dremel is probably too much for the tip.

Soldering tips are a multi-layered structure, made mostly of copper that is then plated in iron, and the very tip plated in tin. Everything but the tip is usually plated with chromium (which is very difficult to get solder to stick to, so the solder stays on the tip). Note that all these plating layers are very thin, on the order of a few to a few dozen microns.

Mechanically abrading the tip will remove any oxide buildup, sure, but it will also damage this layered structure. If you abrade away the tin, you will be left with exposed iron, which will not carry solder, and which can rust when exposed to air and high temperatures. Tip tinner may be able to re-plate the parts with scratched-off tin, but the real problem is if you abrade through the iron layer: in that case, you've exposed the copper, and *now* you've thoroughly destroyed your tip. You may not be aware of this, but copper actually dissolves in solder, and surprisingly quickly too. As you keep using the iron, you'll find that the tip grows more and more pitted as parts of it dissolve and get left behind in solder joints and on your tip cleaner.

There is no practical way to re-apply the iron plating at home, so you'll just need to get a new tip if it was damaged this way. You need a new tip anyway--that one is way too oxidized to be used--but remember this in the future.